# Python, list of nested repeated keys

Tags: python, list, nested, key

I would like to process this json data in python:

```
{"data":
   [{"CU":"AGLD","CO": [{"chain":"ERC20"}],                 "fn":"Adventure Gold"}, 
    {"CU":"ACH","CO":  [{"chain":"ERC20"},    {"chain":"BEP20"}],   "fn":"Alchemy"}]}
```

I would like to get the value of all "chain"s. For example like this:

```
CU  chains:
AGLD    ERC20
ACH     ERC20
ACH     BEP20
```

I tried with a for loop, but (in the case of several "chain"s) it returns only the last value of "chain" for example ACH BEP20. Does not return ACH ERC20.

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried. Make sure that it's a [mcve]. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: what did you try? where is your code?

Comment: maybe you should use nested `for`-loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you used `for`-loop but you need neested `for`-loops - like this:

```
data = {"data": [
    {"CU":"AGLD", "CO": [{"chain": "ERC20"}],                    "fn":"Adventure Gold"}, 
    {"CU":"ACH",  "CO": [{"chain": "ERC20"}, {"chain":"BEP20"}], "fn":"Alchemy"}
]}

for item in data['data']:
    for subitem in item['CO']:
        print(item['CU'], subitem['chain'])
```

Result:

```
AGLD ERC20
ACH ERC20
ACH BEP20
```

---

**BTW:**

You didn't show how you keep it but if you keep in dictionary then you need list to keep all values `result[key] = [value1, value2]`. If you will assing `result[key] = value` then you get only last item.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way to do it in a less complicated manner:

```
# data = {"data": ...}

chains = sum([[i['CU']] + [j['chain'] for j in i['CO']] for i in data['data']], [])
print(chains)

# Output:
# ['AGLD', 'ERC20', 'SCT', 'SOL', 'BBF', 'ERC20', 'ACH', 'ERC20', 'BEP20', 'ISP', 'ERC20', 'BEP20', 'ACK', 'BEP20']
```

Comment: I see the question has been modified to better reflect the expected outcome.